# pgAdmin4 "Could not connect to the server"

Tags: postgresql, windows-10, pgadmin-4

I was using PostgreSQL with pgAdmin 4 to manage my Databe in a PostgreSQL server, but today, i just start pgAdmin to add some tables and i can´t connect to the server, it gives me this error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP 
connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Im on W10

Here´s some pictures:

[PostgreSQL pgAdmin4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeeRU.png)

[image: When I try to restart de service]

Comment: Sounds like you haven't got the server running (perhaps you installed it but didn't set it to launch automatically after each reboot?).  You don't mention your operating system, so just search on how to start the server for your particular OS.

Comment: You´re rigth, sorry for that, im new on this, Im On W10, i already updated question information.